# How to tell flask-admin to use alternative representation when displaying Foreign Key Fields?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

How can I tell flask-admin to use an alternative representation for Foreign Key Fields such as the following in this RoleUser link table?

[image: Flask-Admin]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to add `__str__` methods (`__unicode__` for Python 2) to your models.

```
class Role(db.Model):
    # snip
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```